# how to make images clickable in a listing (numerous thumbnails)

Tags: views

in our event_parent https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9ELE.jpg content view we have a listing (field_listing) field that contains numerous thumbnails and they need to redirect to their specified event page. we are on drupal 7

Answer (score 1):

Click on the field for the image and you should see "link image to" and you can select "content". Set the filter criteria so that the system knows what content to link to. Also, the image should be coming from the content, such as as a thumbnail.

Comment: Hi,For some reason i dont see that option ( i have been looking for it even before my post) in the event parent/ articles/ or any content type where images are being used. I did however find the option in the filetypes directory and i changed it to content http://imgur.com/a/4WkdY like you advised me to. When i refresh the pages the images are still not clickable :( any idea why this could be? Thank you for respoding :)